# Metacity toggle fullscreen not working under Lucid; worked with Karmic

Tags: gnome, fullscreen, metacity, ubuntu-10.04

I'm working on a 11" screen, so I frequently want to use applications in fullscreen. I'm no expert on GNOME, but I remember doing a search a while back, and finding out about *metacity*, and how to use that to allow any window to be put in fullscreen. This worked great on Karmic, but it doesn't seem to be working under Lucid. Here's what I do.

1. Run `gconf-editor`.
2. Go to `/apps/metacity/window_keybindings`.
3. Change `toggle_fullscreen` from `disabled` to `<Control><Shift>F`.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I know that I've got the right syntax because I can see other shortcuts and use them as a template. I have no idea what's wrong, and no idea how to move forwards/debug. Any suggestions much appreciated.

TIA

Andy